# pst-solides3d problem with MacTeX

Tags: pstricks

With MacTeX, the following official example doesn't compile. Why ?

```
\documentclass{standalone}
    \usepackage[pdf]{pstricks}
    \usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(-5,-5)(5,5)
    \psset{viewpoint=20 25 15,Decran=50,solidmemory}
    \axesIIID(0,0,0)(2,2,2)
    \psSolid[name=longbox,
        object=parallelepiped,
        a=3,b=.2,c=.2,
        fillcolor=blue](.5,.5,.5)
    \psSolid[
        name=flatbox,
        object=parallelepiped,
        a=.25,b=2,c=2,
        fillcolor=yellow](.5,.5,.5)
    \psSolid[object=fusion,
        action=draw,
        base=flatbox longbox]
        (0,0,0)
    \composeSolid
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

Here is the log.

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.16 (TeX Live 2015) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./3D.tex
LaTeX2e <2016/02/01>
Babel <3.9n> and hyphenation patterns for 79 languages loaded.
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cls
Document Class: standalone 2015/07/15 v1.2 Class to compile TeX sub-files stand
alone
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifluatex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/standalone/standalone.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pstricks/pstricks.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xcolor/xcolor.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/color.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pdftex-def/pdftex.def
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/infwarerr.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ltxcmds.sty)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/pst-xkey.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex
`pst-fp' v0.05, 2010/01/17 (hv))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common.te
x
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfutil-common-li
sts.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeys.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgfkeysfiltered.c
ode.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/utilities/pgffor.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmath.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathcalc.code.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathutil.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathparser.code.tex
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.code.
tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.basic
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.trigo
nometric.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.rando
m.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.compa
rison.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.base.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.round
.code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.misc.
code.tex)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfunctions.integ
erarithmetics.code.tex)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pgf/math/pgfmathfloat.code.tex)
))
`PSTricks' v2.64b  <2015/14/11> (tvz)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pstricks.con))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pstricks/pst-fp.tex))
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/pst-solides3d/pst-solides3d.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-solides3d/pst-solides3d.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/pst-node/pst-node.tex
 v1.35, 2014/08/04)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/generic/multido/multido.tex
 v1.42, 2010/05/14 <tvz>) `PSTSOLIDESIIID' v4.30, 2015/12/17)) (./3D.aux)
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
)
./3D.tex:9: Undefined control sequence.
<recently read> \c@lor@to@ps 

l.9     \axesIIID(0,0,0)(2,2,2)

? 
Process aborted
```

Is there a way to fix the problem ?

Comment: As far as I know, the `pdf` option to pstricks doesn't work anymore. You have to load explicitly `auto-pst-pdf` *after* `pstricks`. Also you have to launch pdflatex with the `--shell-escape` switch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a problem with `standalone` and the `pdf`option. Simpy use `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-solides3d}

\begin{document}

\psset{viewpoint=20 25 15,Decran=50,solidmemory}
\begin{pspicture}(-3,-2)(3,3)
\axesIIID(0,0,0)(2,2,2)
\psSolid[name=longbox,object=parallelepiped,a=3,b=.2,c=.2,fillcolor=blue](.5,.5,.5)
\psSolid[name=flatbox,object=parallelepiped,a=.25,b=2,c=2,fillcolor=yellow](.5,.5,.5)
\psSolid[object=fusion,action=draw,base=flatbox longbox](0,0,0)
\composeSolid
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This works too but `\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}` is "simpler".

Comment: sure, but not with documentclass `standalone`

Comment: Yes  That is right.